# C# equivalent of Get-AzEventHubNamespaceKey

Tags: azure

We are looking to write a C# function that can return the connection string for an EventHub in our application.

We understand that there is a PowerShell Get-AzEventHubNamespaceKey that can do it, but looking for a C# equivalent.

Any suggestions welcome.

MrHappyhead

Answer (score 0):

To help anybody else out there looking for something like this, it is possible to use the Azure.Management.% namespaces.

For example for an EventHub:

```
EventHubManagementClient eventHubClient = new EventHubManagementClient(tokenCredentials);
```

You can then use

```
AccessKeys accessKeys = await eventHubClient.Namespaces.ListKeysAsync(resourceGroup, eventHubNamespace,authorisationRuleName);
```

It is better to use the Namespaces as opposed to eventhubs, because the former provides connection strings in the scenario that you are using Geo DR - e.g. you can obtain the Primary/Secondary alias connection strings.